# I have an erro in a mocha test, testing nodejs

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I have this method

```
getUser: function(req, res) {
var roomId = req.params.id;
console.log(roomId);
    User.findById(roomId).exec((err, room) => {
    // Room.find({ availability: true }).exec((err, room) => {
    if (err || !room) {
        return res.status(404).send({
            status: 'error',
            message: 'No existe la habitacion'
        });
    }

    return res.status(200).send({
        status: 'success',
        room
    });
});
```

},
and this test

```
describe('users', ()=>{
    let findStub;
    let deleteStub;
    let sampleUser;
    let mailerStub;

    beforeEach(()=>{
        sampleUser = {
            id: 123,
            name: 'foo',
            email: 'foo@bar.com',
            save: sandbox.stub().resolves()
        }

        findStub = sandbox.stub(mongoose.Model, 'findById').resolves(sampleUser);
        deleteStub = sandbox.stub(mongoose.Model, 'remove').resolves('fake_remove_result');
        
    })

    afterEach(()=>{
        sandbox.restore();
        users = rewire('./user');
    })
```

users
get
should check for an id:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'body')
at Object.getUser (controllers/user.js:113:22)

the error is in this line var params= req.body; in the method. I dont know how to fix it.

```
    context('get', ()=>{
        it('should check for an id', (done)=>{
            users.getUser(null, (err, result)=>{
                expect(err).to.exist;
                expect(err.message).to.equal('Invalid user id');
                done();
            })
        })
```

I have changed the method. I tested with postman it is working. but the test fails

```
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you provided `null` as `req` in this line

```
users.getUser(null, (err, result)=>{
```

You need to provide some mock value there, something like this

```
            users.getUser({body: {id: '123' // provide your mock values here}}, (err, result)=>{
                expect(err).to.exist;
                expect(err.message).to.equal('Invalid user id');
                done();
            })
```

and should this line be `params.id` instead of `req.params.id`?

```
 var params = req.body;
    User.findById(params.id //this should be params.id?, function (err, result) {
```

Comment: I changed null per body  { id:123 but I got TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Comment: The message is pretty clear, that's because you passing `req.params.id`, but I think it should be `params.id`

Comment: no. if I use params.id without req the method fails with postman